# How to go to a particular line in TeXShop?

Tags: editors, mac, texshop, forward-inverse-search

I want to edit the output PDF file, but it is difficult to find the correct place in the source editor. What is the keyboard shortcut to jump from a place in the output PDF to the corresponding place in the source of the document?

I am using the editor TeXShop with Mac OS X.

Comment: Could you please tell what editor you are using. Some editors do and others don't provide the feature you described.

Comment: TexShop is the one I am using

Comment: COMMAND+SHIFT+CLICK should be the required maneuver.

Comment: @egreg Yes. This is working.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The maneuver for going back and forth from the LaTeX file to the PDF file and conversely is

> Command+Shift+Click

Answer (score 10):

Actually, Command+Click is sufficient to switch between source and pdf file with TeXShop. (This answer was meant as a comment, but "I must have 50 reputation to comment"…)

Answer (score -1):

## Shell-Alternative: Grep-function

It is independent of any kind of editors.
The idea is to find the place of interest (string as letters, words or longer fragment) by applying a search on (all) the `*.tex` file(s).

For multiple file search, you can use the shell command `grep -r "source code" *.tex`, as you have a shell too in OS X.